# Rows of the Collatz tree

Tags: code-golf, sequence, arithmetic, binary-tree

Consider a binary tree built the following way:

- The root node is \$1\$
- For a given node \$n\$:

  - If \$n\$ is odd, its only child is \$2n\$
  - If \$n\$ is even, one of its children is \$2n\$. If \$\frac {n-1} 3\$ is an integer and not already part of the tree, its right child is \$\frac {n-1} 3\$
- Recursively and infinitely define the tree this way, beginning from the root node.

The resulting tree begins like this:

[image: collatz tree]

and continues forever, conjectured to contain all positive integers. If you choose any integer on this tree and work your way up through its parents, you'll  find the [Collatz path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture) to \$1\$ for that integer. This is called a *Collatz graph*

[This](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/0e/Collatz-tree%2C_depth%3D20.svg) is that tree to a depth of 20.

We can read this tree as rows, from left to right, to create a list of lists:

```
[[1], [2], [4], [8], [16], [32, 5], [64, 10], [128, 21, 20, 3], [256, 42, 40, 6], [512, 85, 84, 80, 13, 12], [1024, 170, 168, 160, 26, 24], [2048, 341, 340, 336, 320, 53, 52, 48], ...
```

Flattened, this is [A088976](https://oeis.org/A088976).

Your program should take a positive integer \$n\$ and output the first \$n\$ rows of this tree. You may output in any format that clearly and consistently shows a separation between each element in the row, and a distinct separation between the rows themselves. For example, spaces for the elements, and newlines for the rows.

[This](https://tio.run/##VZBBboNADEXXcApvqoxT0pSgbCJxhV6AogoVoyKBZzQMjdrLU3ugUbJ9fvO/x@4nfFkulqWlDj7tMDTh98Pb62Q4g@CJoIQ3y4SXNOm7lfRTREKSzaiqvK6jwFCW8KojT2H2HF@kaSKR6onUWQ9sW4lZh9Uhr6Nvry@Nc8StOcE@KihYM9V@glOMhoZbMBEdIEfhxa3yPuNOOR6hwHRtpoFGbRbzsqb/k2keje6TyZZ4S/M02m8yKmnE9qnHQ2nLdqxnqITVojrfczD7B1NJz24OBhEzmMjJTXbvvMNlyc9/) is a sample program (ungolfed) that takes an integer and outputs each list on a line.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code in bytes wins.

Comment: does each row need to be in this particular order?

Comment: @hyper-neutrino Yes, the order should be the same as shown - descending down the tree, with each row being left to right

Comment: @Arnauld Right, forget to mention that the tree doesn't contain duplicate nodes, so \$1\$ cannot appear twice (and is already the root node)

Comment: May we output only the \$n\$th row?

Comment: @att No, the output should be the first \$n\$

Answer (score 16):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), <sup><s>37</s></sup> 35 bytes

```
{x#x(,/{(4=6!x*4<x)(-6!)\2*x}')\,1}
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.bitbucket.io/k#eJxLs6quUK7Q0NGv1jCxNVOs0DKxqdDU0DVT1Iwx0qqoVdeM0TGs5eJKUzA0AAD90ArT)

#### How it works

"n is even and `(n-1)/3` is an integer" is equivalent to "n is 4 mod 6".

Avoiding the cycles is achieved by simply not allowing 4 to generate 1:

**Claim:** A cycle cannot be formed midway into the tree. Any cycle in the tree must include the root, i.e. the number 1.

**Proof:** Let's assume a node \$a_0\$ has a child \$a_1\$, which has a child \$a_2\$, ..., which has a child \$a_n\$, which in turn has a child \$a_0\$. Also, let's call the Collatz \$3n+1\$ function \$f(x)\$. Then the following holds:

$$
f(a_1) = a_0, f(a_2) = a_1, \cdots, f(a_n) = a_{n-1}, f(a_0) = a_n
$$

If \$a_0\$ has a parent (let's call it \$a_{-1}\$), then \$f(a_0) = a_{-1}\$, which implies \$a_{-1} = a_n\$, and therefore \$a_{-1}, a_0, \cdots, a_{n-1}\$ is also a cycle (which is one level closer to the root of the tree than \$a_0, \cdots, a_n\$). The same logic can be applied to \$a_{-1}\$, \$a_{-2}\$, ..., until the highest node reaches the root. Therefore, every cycle that exists in this tree goes through the root, i.e. the number 1. \$\blacksquare\$

The only cycle that involves the number 1 is the `[1, 2, 4]` cycle. Therefore, it suffices to prevent this cycle (i.e. stop 4 from generating 1) to prevent all cycles in the tree.

```
{x#x( ... )\,1}    start with [1], iterate x times and collect values,
                   and take first x values...
,/{ ... }'           apply to each number and flatten...
2*x                    start with twice the input,
(-6!)\                 and append its floor division by 6 if
(4=6!x*4<x)            the original input is 4 mod 6 and it is over 4
```

Comment: What are the advantages of using ngn/k vs oK vs shakti?

Comment: @Jonah The obvious advantage is CGCC post support in the online interpreter. Other than that, ngn/k has (IMO) lower chance of encountering "weird" bugs compared to oK, and Shakti is not free and its built-ins are still changing.

Comment: Also how does your code deal with the "and not already part of the tree" constraint?

Comment: By not allowing 4 to go back to 1... but now I realize it assumes the Collatz conjecture is true. I guess I should find a different solution that doesn't depend on it. **Edit:** Wait no, I think it actually works without assuming it. I'll add an explanation on it.

Comment: direct BQN translation(42): `{(∾´{⌊6÷˜⍟(↕1+4=6|×4<)2×}¨)⍟(↕)⥊1}`

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jellylanguage), 23 bytes

```
ḤḤ,’÷3ƊƊḂ?€FḞƑƇ>Ƈ1
1ÇÐ¡
```

[Try It Online!](https://jht.hyper-neutrino.xyz/tio#WyIiLCLhuKThuKQs4oCZw7czxorGiuG4gj/igqxG4biexpHGhz7GhzFcbjHDh8OQwqEiLCLDh8WS4bmY4oKsWSIsIiIsWyIxNSJdXQ==)

I doubt this is optimal; I kind of ended up patching together like three fixes in a row on my original idea. Might retry later if I have time and remember.

Comment: [-1 byte](https://jht.hyper-neutrino.xyz/tio#WyIiLCLigJnDtzPhua3huKThuZbhuIJ9wqEpRuG4nsaRxoc+xocxXG4xw4fDkMKhIiwiw4fFkuG5mOKCrFkiLCIiLFsiMTUiXV0=)

Comment: ...and [three more](https://jht.hyper-neutrino.xyz/tio#WyIiLCLhuILIr+KAmcO3M+G5reG4pClG4biexpHGh+G4nzFcbjHDh8OQwqEiLCLDh8WS4bmY4oKsWSIsIiIsWyIxNSJdXQ==)

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES10), 70 bytes

```javascript
f=(n,a=[1])=>n--?a+`
`+f(n,a.flatMap(x=>x%6-4|x<5?2*x:[2*x,~-x/3])):''
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/f8/zVYjTyfRNtowVtPWLk9X1z5RO4ErQTsNJKqXlpNY4ptYoFFha1ehaqZrUlNhY2pvpFVhFQ0kdOp0K/SNYzU1rdTV/yfn5xXn56Tq5eSna6RpGBppav4HAA)

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>77</s> <s>75</s> 72 bytes

-5 bytes thanks to [Dude coinheringaahing](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/66833/dude-coinheringaahing), [G B](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/18535/g-b) and [xnor](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/20260/xnor)!

```python
r=1,
exec'print r;r=sum([[2*i]+[i/3][:i%6==4<i]for i in r],[]);'*input()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcE7CoAwDADQ3VNkkfopiB8c1JwkZBLFDLYltqCnr@@FL17eDTkr9rY43mM3QcVF0FXxSXdFNDTCLUk3Mi1SzojTJnx6BQFxoGyJ69U04kKKVZ1zP/0)

---

Assuming the Collatz conjecture holds, we can generate the tree by sorting Collatz paths. This is a lot longer, but maybe a bit more interesting:

```python
c=lambda x:-1/x*[x]or c([x/2,3*x-1][x%2])+[x]
k=0
exec'print[-w[k]for w in sorted(c(p)for p in range(-2**k,0)if-~k==len(c(p)))];k+=1;'*input()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcpBEoIgGEDhvadg0wgoo1CrHE7CsDDEYjBkiMa/TVcnbfu9Fz/5sQZRipHL@LxNI4Ir4x1QBXpNyGAFnWjPFBjXCk5Ck2YvlZd9ZcGaOiYXsmKb8nre/w25gF5rynbCBkdyWDwsjeFuMROU@rYnbmZfL@Viw/8iRA@@kXyoqQvxnTEphV9@)

Comment: [75 bytes](https://tio.run/##BcE7DoAgDADQ3VOwGPEXoxIHkZM0nQzGDgKpkOji1fG98MbTuylnNjBiYR@7V4HJRcGazZ0uCTA1hC18PQ0zwkrlYozaCA/PggQ5wdgB1rpqyIUUZZ3zqH4)

Comment: Cut 2 bytes: the integer division (x+1)/3 is the same as x/3

Comment: [70 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/v8jWUIcrtSI1Wb2gKDOvRKHIusi2uDRXIzo6U99Yx0grMzY6U9VM0dZENdMqNi2/SCFTITNPoShWJzpW01pdKzOvoLREQ/P/f0MTAA "Python 2 – Try It Online")

Comment: @xnor I included the `1,` but the other suggestion changes the order of nodes in the tree, which is not allowed

Answer (score 3):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 48 bytes

```
<6&(([:;<@(((],<.@%~)+:)#~1,(4<])*4=|)"0)&.>)<@1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/bczUNDSiraxtHDQ0NGJ1bPQcVOs0ta00lesMdTRMbGI1tUxsazSVDDTV9Ow0bRwM/2typSZn5CukKRga/AcA)

Just a port of [Bubbler's nice K answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/233511/15469) into J, to see how they'd compare.

The required boxing to handle ragged arrays, as well as some other details, made it harder to golf in J.

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 60 bytes

```perl
$_=1;for$x(2.."@F"){s,\d+,2*$&.($&%6-4|$&<5?'':(1-$&)/3),ge}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcFLCsIwFAXQ@V1GeaaNJtGXn3905CoEEawiFBNaB4K6deM5ue27UAqdtry@pp5ejTWm2h8q@R7U8TJRdkzCNCRGUfsPiU3Y1fWqYU1CTp1Ut/ZbCsPCwSMgYo4FluAZmMEW7MAeHMDxl/Lznh5D0efc/QE)

For each input line:

```perl
$_=1;               # init output string $_ with '1'
for$x(2.."@F"){     # do input-1 times, input number is in "@F" due to -a
  s,\d+,            # search-replace all positive ints in $_ with:
     2*$&           # 2 * the current int now in $&
     .              # and possibly also another number
     (
       $&%6-4|$&<5  # ...if $& % 6 == 4 and $& > 4
       ? ''
       : (1-$&)/3   # negative x where x = ($&-1)/3 using '-' as separator
     )
   ,ge              # g=global, e=replacement from code not string
}
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 58 bytes

```
NestList[If[#~Mod~6==4<#,##&,#&][2#,--+#/3]&/@#&,{1},#-1]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b73y@1uMQns7gk2jMtWrnONz@lzszW1sRGWUdZWU1HWS022khZR1dXW1nfOFZN3wEoVm1Yq6Osaxir9j@gKDOvRN8hzcHI4D8A)

Returns a list of row-lists.

Comment: `--+#/3` is neat.

Answer (score 3):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>66</s> 64 bytes

```ruby
->n{[a=[1]]+(2..n).map{a=a.flat_map{|x|[x*2,x%6==4?x/3:1]-[1]}}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y6vOjrRNtowNlZbw0hPL09TLzexoDrRNlEvLSexJB7Eqamoia7QMtKpUDWztTWxr9A3tjKM1QVqqa2t/V@gkBZtaBr7HwA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>69</s> 57 bytes

```hs
(`take`iterate(>>=g)[1])
g n=2*n:[n`div`3|n`mod`6==4,n>4]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcExDoMwDADAnVd4YICqHaCoQyXnIxTJFiRpRDARREy8HXP35322MarDn1aUebYUst0428oY9HXfDHXhQbB9yLcXmsJB71NoWSf6IHZPMd2gCwcBhLQFyVCCg6bVa3SR/a6vMaUb)

- saved 12 bytes thanks to @DelfadOr !
- Based on [@ovs answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/233542/98541)

57 bytes alternative provided by @xnor

```hs
(`take`iterate(>>=g)[1])
g n=2*n:[k|k<-[2,4..n],3*k+4==n]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcExDoMwDADAva/w0AEoIJEyVTUfCZGwUJJGTq0IMvbtNXcfOtnnrAFXbbZK7LdU/UHVN8uCsbWTa28RBE0nL8s/fg/W9PM4iuufHT9mRHH6pSSAUI4kFe4QYDL630OmeOqwl3IB)

Comment: [57 bytes](https://tio.run/##BcExDoMwDADAnVd4YICqHaCoQyXnIxTJFiRpRDARREy8HXP35322MarDn1aUebYUst0428oY9HXfDHXhQbB9yLcXmsJB71NoWSf6IHZPMd2gCwcBhLQFyVCCg6bVa3SR/a6vMaUb "Haskell – Try It Online")

Comment: [Also turns out to be 57](https://tio.run/##BcExDoMwDADAva/w0AEoIJEyVTUfCZGwUJJGTq0IMvbtNXcfOtnnrAFXbbZK7LdU/UHVN8uCsbWTa28RBE0nL8s/fg/W9PM4iuufHT9mRHH6pSSAUI4kFe4QYDL630OmeOqwl3IB "Haskell – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 38 bytes

```
⊞υ¹ＦＮ«Ｉυ↓≔υη≔⟦⟧υＦη«⊞υ⊗κ¿∧›κ⁴⁼⁴﹪κ⁶⊞υ÷κ³
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Tc2xCsIwEAbguX2KGy8QB7U46CRWxEHpLg5pG20wJprk6iA@e2wKgrf9d8f3N51wjRU6xop8h8Rhylb5xTrAvXlQONK9lg4Zg3eeVU6ZgBvhAxIb3rKD7SUuS/syKa29V1eTjO4vns4cKOUR7UYo@5WVlmotW7yNXKYugGvT4s5JEYbaG4eCcdg@SWiPBYeDbUnbtF@wYeDn7E0oVa9amU7zEfvknxinszjp9Rc) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
⊞υ¹
```

Start with the first row of just `1`.

```
ＦＮ«
```

Loop over the desired number of rows.

```
Ｉυ
```

Output each element on its own line.

```
↓
```

Leave a blank line between rows.

```
≔υη
```

Save the current row.

```
≔⟦⟧υ
```

Start a new row.

```
Ｆη«
```

Loop over the saved row.

```
⊞υ⊗κ
```

Add the current element, doubled.

```
¿∧›κ⁴⁼⁴﹪κ⁶
```

If the current element is greater than 4 but equal to 4 modulo 6, then...

```
⊞υ÷κ³
```

... add the current element, integer divided by 3.

Answer (score 2):

### [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 63 bytes

```perl
@n=1;map{say"@n";@n=map{$_*2,$_<5||$_%6-4?():($_-1)/3}@n}0..pop
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9X1qcqlBmqmdoYP3fIc/W0Do3saC6OLFSySFPyRooAOKqxGsZ6ajE25jW1KjEq5rpmthraFppqMTrGmrqG9c65NUa6OkV5Bf8///f0BgA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 67 bytes

```julia
>(n,a=[1])=show(a),0<n-1>[(a.|>j->[2j;~-j÷3][1:1+(j%6==4<j)])...;]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPj/304jTyfRNtowVtO2OCO/XCNRU8fAJk/X0C5aI1Gvxi5L1y7aKMu6Tjfr8Hbj2GhDK0NtjSxVM1tbE5sszVhNPT0961igGUYGmv8B)

based on [ovs's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/233542/98541)

output is in the form

```julia
[1][2][4][8][16][32, 5][64, 10][128, 21, 20, 3]...
```